# how to programmatically dump call stack of ALL threads, not just current thread [NSThread callStackSymbols]

Tags: macos, fullscreen, nswindow, nsthread, callstack

how to NSLog the call stacks of ALL threads, not just the current thread?

(I'm aware of [NSThread callStackSymbols], which is useful)

---

What I'm trying to achieve:

whenever a specific condition happens:

```
  // on main thread
  if ( timeout )
  {
      NSLog ALL threads call stacks
  }
```

I'm trying to track down a hard-to-reproduce bug which likely has multiple causes.

(Namely, I need to NEVER show the desktop while reconfiguring full screen NSWindows for multiple NSScreens)

I know that certain device drivers can cause my bug, but I'm beginning to suspect that nearly *all* device drivers can cause it,
including audio, video, camera, usb, bluetooth, 3rd party, etc.

Comment: It sounds like you maybe need to [capture the displays](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_display_services?language=objc#1655961) and/or [kiosk mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: We used to use CGDisplayCapture() for years.  We abandoned CGDisplayCapture() since the introduction of Mac Pro 2013, because of subtle problems when displays are plugged/unplugged, a frequent use-case for us.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Hmm... maybe I'll temporarily CGCaptureAllDisplays() followed by CGReleaseAllDisplays().  The problem typically only happens for a frame or two.  Kiosk mode for a couple frames may work too.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't think that either of those would work as brief mechanisms. Does `NSDisableScreenUpdates()` (and later re-enabling) help? Could you create your own shielding windows as capturing the display does? That is, create large black borderless windows for each screen, which override `-constrainFrameRect:toScreen:` to prevent constraining.

Comment: sounds promising.  I've used -[NSWindow disableScreenUpdatesUntilFlush], but NSDisableScreenUpdates() sounds better **"This function permits operations on multiple windows to appear atomic to the user"